# The difference between two ways of assigning java objects

Tags: java

1:

```
  Models models= new Models(){
            {
                setName(name);
            }
        };
```

2:

```
Models models= new Models()
models.setName(name)
```

Was the `models` reference I got set?

Comment: Woah, just learned about double brace initialization. Cool.

Comment: Second won't work. Where are the semicolons?? :p

Comment: @LambdaNinja it is cool in the same way that a poisonous snake is cool - that is, until it turns round and bites you. Please do not think this is a good practice.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks for the heads-up.